# Как ускорить этот код?

Tags: c++, файлы, sqlite, visual-c++

```
   ifstream f("names.txt");

   string s; int i=0;
   while (!f.eof()) {
       getline(f,s);
       s="INSERT INTO ACCS VALUES('"+s+"',1 ,1,0);";
       sqlite3_exec(db, s.c_str(), NULL, NULL, &error);
   }   
   sqlite3_close(db);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте явные транзакции.

```
sqlite3_exec(db, "BEGIN TRANSACTION;", NULL, NULL, &error);
ifstream f("names.txt");

string s; int i=0;
while (!f.eof()) {
  getline(f,s);
  s="INSERT INTO ACCS VALUES('"+s+"',1 ,1,0);";
  sqlite3_exec(db, s.c_str(), NULL, NULL, &error);
}
sqlite3_exec(db, "COMMIT TRANSACTION;", NULL, NULL, &error);

sqlite3_close(db);
```

Comment: >sqlite3_exec("BEGIN TRANSACTION;");
пишет const char* несовместим с параметром типа sqlite3*

Comment: о, я упустил... Там еще пара параметром. Я поправлю ответ.

Answer (score 0):

1. не выполняйте одиночный запрос по каждой записи. 
   В s соберите все, что нужно отправить на insert и скопом выполните sqlite3_exec